# program not storing/returning array properly

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a simple program that stores an array and then returns it. However, it is not returning all of the numbers correctly, specifically toward the end of the array. Here is an example of the output:

```
Please enter number of numbers
5
Please enter number 1
2
Please enter number 2
3
Please enter number 3
5
Please enter number 4
6
Please enter number 5
7
Number 1 is 2
Number 2 is 3
Number 3 is 5
Number 4 is 14
Number 5 is 1
logout

[Process completed]

and here is my code:

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i, num;
    int x[num];

    printf("Please enter number of numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Please enter number %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Number %d is %d\n", i + 1, x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding the calls to the scanf() function:  the returned value (not the converted parameter value) needs to be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before scanning num you are doing `int x[num]` and as `num` stores garbage value you aren't getting the correct output.

```
int main (void) {
    int i, num;
   // int x[num]; // num is not defined here

    printf("Please enter number of numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
     int x[num];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Please enter number %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Number %d is %d\n", i + 1, x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note:  This is only valid C99 and later.  Using `malloc` to allocate the array is far more portable.  Which of the two is the "best practice" depends on industry / application.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Yeah...  How  is this implemented in C99..? Is the malloc indirectly called when we declare x[num] ?

Comment: In theory it could just be a stack pointer manipulation just like a fixed-size array.  Hidden calls to `malloc` and `free` would also probably work.  But most of my low level debugging experience is w/ C89 (or close to it), so I couldn't really tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I think You should initialise the num variable so that it will not be having the garbage values initially..